# Use GridFieldManager or TableLayoutManager

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I've been using TableLayoutManager as defined in the BlackBerry KnowledgeBase article [Create a rich UI layout with TableLayoutManager](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Create-a-rich-UI-layout-with-TableLayoutManager/ta-p/445299)

I'm considering using [GridFieldManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/GridFieldManager.html) instead.
Is GridFieldManager used for the same purpose? Are there advantages that GridFieldManager has over TableLayoutManager and vice versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, however here is what I have:

> Are there advantages that GridFieldManager has over TableLayoutManager and vice versa?

At a glance - `GridFieldManager` is a comparatively new component (since API 5.0.0), while you can use `TableLayoutManager` on much older APIs (since 4.2). So if you're writting an app to be run on those pre-5.0 devices, then I think you should prefer `TableLayoutManager`.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I thought.

Comment: Arhimed, how would you comment about GridFieldManager not offering any implementation for sublayout(...). My code is overriding that method to adjsut some child positions and works fine on 6.0.0 JRE, but does not compile on 5.0.0 JRE. removing the call to super.sublayout(...) makees it compile, but the GridFieldManager  appears broken - I only get a blank screen. Thanks

Comment: @kellogs: It's really difficult to comment. I'd recommend to ask about this issue as a separate StackOverflow question posing your code.

Comment: just for the record, what breaks it is overriding sublayout (and removing the call to super.sublayout()). Not overriding it altogether results in a working GridFieldManager. And I have just learnt how to tweak it so that there would be no need for overriding subayout :)